# Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information. maybe eror in react-native-camera

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo, build.gradle, react-native-camera

Running 'gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
10%
20%.
30%
40%
50%.
60%.
70%.
80%.
90%.
100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.3!
Here are the highlights of this release:

- Faster Java compilation
- Reduced memory usage
- Support for running on Java 20
  For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/release-notes.html
  To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
  Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build

> Configure project :
> Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Configure project :expo-modules-core
> Checking the license for package NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
> License for package NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 accepted.
> Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393".
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393" ready.
> Installing NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393" complete.
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393" finished.
> Configure project :expo-modules-core$android-annotation
> Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
> Configure project :expo
> Using expo modules

- expo-camera (14.1.1)
- expo-constants (15.4.5)
- expo-file-system (16.0.8)
- expo-font (11.10.3)

  - expo-keep-awake (12.8.2)
  - expo-media-library (15.9.1)
  - expo-modules-core (1.11.12)
  - expo-modules-core$android-annotation (1.11.12)
  - expo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor (1.11.12)
  - expo-permissions (14.4.0)

> Configure project :react-native-vision-camera
> [VisionCamera] react-native-worklets-core not found, Frame Processors disabled!
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalReportRelease'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :react-native-camera.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > The consumer was configured to find a component for use during runtime, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-camera:
> - generalReleaseRuntimeElements
> - mlkitReleaseRuntimeElements
> All of them match the consumer attributes:
> - Variant 'generalReleaseRuntimeElements' capability parkir:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-camera' with value 'general' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'generalRelease' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
> - Provides attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'general' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Variant 'mlkitReleaseRuntimeElements' capability parkir:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-camera' with value 'mlkit' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'mlkitRelease' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
> - Provides attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'mlkit' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
> - Variant 'generalDebugApiElements' capability parkir:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1':
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
> - Variant 'generalDebugRuntimeElements' capability parkir:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1':
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
> - Variant 'generalReleaseApiElements' capability parkir:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
> - Variant 'mlkitDebugApiElements' capability parkir:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1':
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
> - Variant 'mlkitDebugRuntimeElements' capability parkir:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1':
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
> - Variant 'mlkitReleaseApiElements' capability parkir:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
> BUILD FAILED in 2m 58s
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
> You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
> For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
> 5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
> Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).